# Change recovery model while the database is in replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-administration, recoverymodel

We have a production database that is in full recovery mode.

This database is being replicated to another server. (transaction replication)

We have maintenance jobs run on Friday nights which include index rebuilding.

Transaction log backup files are huge after this maintenance job.

So I am thinking of changing the recovery model to simple before the maintenance job starts and change it back to full after the maintenance job.

Will this method impact the replication?

I know replication can work with any recovery model but not sure whether switching recovery models full to simple and then simple to full will have any impact on replication?

Any help/guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know replication can work with any recovery model but not sure whether switching recovery models full to simple and then simple to full will have any impact on replication?

Replication is not dependant on recovery model.Log reader agent scans the log and inserts them as commands in distributor database .log space can be reused only at this point of time  after the insert is done then only log will get truncated(space can be reused).

So even if you change recovery model to full or simple,those settings won't affect replication and are not replicated

Comment: Also consider the impacts on the Backup plan

Comment: @Hybris95 when a backup is running,log will be not truncated

Comment: I mean, switching from Full to Simple model may lead to the impossibility of restoring the transactions afterwards. A new full backup will be required to preserve the RPO.